# How to perform untarring in parallel (pyspark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, tar

I have a 13 GB bzipped tar file in pyspark.

I can read the bzipped file into an RDD and Spark will split the bzipped file into partitions because bzip2 is a splittable file format. I can even then see the RDD contains 400 partitions. Each partition contains the uncompressed bzipped data (part of the tar file).

However considering that tar files are not splittable (from my understanding) I cant perform an untar operation on each of these 400 partitions

```
# The following RDD contains 400 partitions

bzipped_rdd = sc.textFile("s3a://some_bucket/file.tar.bz2")

bzipped_rdd.saveAsTextFile("data_directory")

# I would like to now perform an untar operation on each partition
```

What is the best way to do this?